# How process result from Alert Dialog? (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I'm working on a small class which can generate Alert dialog boxes. The constructor of the class looks like this:

```
void popupMessage(String title, String message, String pText, String nText, boolean cancelable) {
        setPopupResult(999);
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(currentActivity);
        dialog.setMessage(message).setCancelable(cancelable);
        dialog.setNegativeButton(nText, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                setPopupResult(0);
            }
        });
        dialog.setPositiveButton(pText, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                setPopupResult(1);
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alert = dialog.create();
        alert.setTitle(title);
        alert.show();
    }
```

as you see based on pressing the yes or no button the code sets the value of a private variable to 0 or 1 which can be accessed by a getter method. (the value is set to 999 at the top, this indicates that the user did no press anything yet)

The problem I'm facing is that from in the calling activity I somehow should be able to capture when the popupResult variable changes from 999 to either 0 or 1. How can I do that?

(I could be wrong handling the Alert dialog like this, feel free to educate me)

Comment: Why do you need an entire class just to construct a dialog? Why not just do it from a function in your activity and have the callbacks point to other functions in your activity?  
Also, don't use "magic numbers" - give your integers meaningful names like this `static final int YES = 1;`

Comment: @LevM. well my point is then in this case it would be reusable. Yes I can put this code to the caller activity but then I need to use (pretty much) duplicated code over and over and over again whenever I want to display an alert. Great ide of the static YES, I'm just learning java. My reason with 999 was that I can (maybe) capture a change, so when the user actually pressed the button.

Comment: Ok, so you want to reuse the dialog construction and display code, but what about the callbacks on the buttons? If it is the caller activity that needs to know the result, why not link the listeners to it, instead of defining them in separate class? You don't even need two separate listeners, because the `which` parameter tells you the button that was clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the user's clicking on your dialog buttons is asynchronous to when you're showing the dialog, one way to do it, would be to provide some kind of callback to your method, that is called when the buttons are clicked.

Example:

```
/* define this inside your dialog class */
public interface Callback {
    void onOkClicked();
    void onCancelClicked();
}

void popupMessage(String title, String message, String pText, String nText, boolean cancelable, Callback callback) {
    ...
        /* positive button clicklistener, for negative button, use callback.onCancelClicked() */
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            callback.onOKClicked();
        }
    ... 
}

/* Using the method */
popupMessage(..., new Callback() {
    void onOKClicked() {
        /* do something when OK was clicked */
    }

    void onCancelClicked() {
        /* do something when Cancel was clicked */
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that you already have the context of the activity in the variable `currentActivity`. 
 Create the method `setPopupResult()` in your activity like this:

```
public void setPopupResult(int x) {
  // your code goes here
}
```

and in `popupMessage()`, if the class of your activity is `MainActivity`:

```
dialog.setNegativeButton(nText, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        ((MainActivity) currentActivity).setPopupResult(0);
    }
});
dialog.setPositiveButton(pText, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        ((MainActivity) currentActivity).setPopupResult(1);            
    }
});
```

Comment: The only problem with this is that I have to implement the setPopupResult method in my MainActivity while the popup can be called from any activities. I think I should go with an Interface, but I'm in the dark. `callingActivity.setPopupResult(0)` gives me an error (can't resolve the method)

Comment: Of course you have to implement `setPopupResult()` in `MainActivity`. After all it's the activity that needs to be informed.

Comment: No it's not. It could be any activites in which I'd like to call the popup from.